# How to use multiple jquery methods for the same values

Tags: jquery

I'm kind of new to jquery and trying to figure out how can I use `&&` or something else to achieve the use of multiple methods (in this case it's `.prop` and `.val`) instead of doing this twice like this:

```
$('input[name=radio1], input[name=radio2]').prop('disabled', true);
$('input[name=radio1], input[name=radio2]').val('');
```

Comment: chaining is preferable here because both function will return `$('input [name=radio1],input[name=radio2]')` instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a technique called `chaining`, that allows us to run multiple jQuery commands, one after the other, on the same element(s)

```
$('input[name=radio1], input[name=radio2]').prop('disabled', true).val('');
```

Or on the similar note, you can store the jQuery object in a variable and later reuse it.

```
var $el = $('input[name=radio1], input[name=radio2]');
$el.prop('disabled', true).val('');
```

Comment: Either that or store `$('input[name=radio1], input[name=radio2]')` in a variable before and reuse it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
$('input[name=radio1], input[name=radio2]').prop('disabled', true).val('');
```